# python "RSA key format is not supported" when reading from .pem file

Tags: python, rsa

Here is my code:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

#Write key to file
key = RSA.generate(4096)
privateKey = key.exportKey()
file1 = open('keyfile.pem', 'wb')
file1.write(privateKey)
file1.close()

#Read key from file
file2 = open('keyfile.pem', 'rb')
key = RSA.importKey(file2.read()) #this is the problem
```

The error is "RSA key format is not supported." Can anyone help me with the best way to write/read the private key from a file?

Comment: You're not closing the `file1` stream. Also, `file2` is never used.

Comment: Sorry I will fix that -- I mixed up versions of my code when I was posting this. That is not what's causing the issue though, as it's still throwing the error when I have that corrected

Comment: I copied your current code and executed it. I see no errors.

Comment: I just realized that I was forgetting to rerun the write part of my code as I was debugging, so the format of the file was different from when I ran the read file part of the code (with different command line arguments) between updates. Sorry for wasting your time on this.

Answer (score 6):

My answer and a little more complicated with pair of keys

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
key = RSA.generate(4096)
f = open('/home/john/Desktop/my_rsa_public.pem', 'wb')
f.close()
f.write(key.publickey().exportKey('PEM'))
f = open('/home/john/Desktop/my_rsa_private.pem', 'wb')
f.write(key.exportKey('PEM'))
f.close()

f = open('/home/john/Desktop/my_rsa_public.pem', 'rb')
f1 = open('/home/john/Desktop/my_rsa_private.pem', 'rb')
key = RSA.importKey(f.read())
key1 = RSA.importKey(f1.read())

x = key.encrypt(b"dddddd",32)

print(x)
z = key1.decrypt(x)
print(z)
```

Comment: You would do well to explain how it solves the OP's problem and why.

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple issues with your code, mainly the way you are reading and writing the key. You never close the file, then open it twice during your read function; try changing your code to:

```
#Write key to file
key = RSA.generate(4096)
f = open('keyfile.pem', 'wb')
f.write(key.exportKey('PEM'))
f.close()

#Read key from file
f = open('keyfile.pem', 'rb')
key = RSA.importKey(f.read())
```

**Result**:

```
<_RSAobj @0x10d3cb2d8 n(4096),e,d,p,q,u,private>
```