# How to fix 'str' object has no attribute 'encrypt'?

Tags: python, rsa

I'm trying to to encrypt a message using a given public key `pubkey` that i read off a file. When I try to run my program I get an error message stating that

> 'str' object has no attribute 'encrypt'.

I have already tried encoding the public key, but I am still getting the same error. Since I need to use these specific public key I cannot generate another random public key.
Following is my code:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
import math

def text_to_int(text):
    """
    Converts text into an integer for use in encryption.
    input: text - a plaintext message
    output: integer - an integer encoding text
    """
    integer = 0
    for char in text:
         if integer > 0:
            integer = integer*256
    integer = integer + ord(char)
return integer

#Read public key
with open('C:\\Users\\alan9\\Downloads\\Assignement2\\Supporting_Files\\HLand_Key.pub', 'rb') as f:
    read_key = f.read()


# use the PUBLIC KEY to encrypt a message:
message = "attack early next week"
message_int = text_to_int(message)
ciphertext = read_key.encrypt(message_int, None)

#Write ciphertext to file 
with open('C:\\Users\\alan9\\Downloads\\Assignement2\\Supporting_Files\\cipher.txt', 'w') as f_write:
    f_write.write(ciphertext)
```

I expect the output to return the encrypted message in a text file named cipher using the specified public key.
Any help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: `str` objects don't have `encrypt`, that's true. You aren't using the RSA module you're importing, and in Python, just importing a module won't be able to add new methods to existing builtin classes.

Comment: `read_key = f.read()` suggests `read_key` is a string, and there is no built-in method of string objects called `encrypt`.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42892875/python-rsa-key-format-is-not-supported-when-reading-from-pem-file